# Prove $2^{n-1} \geq n$ where n is a natural number

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I am working through a book called *Algebraic Inequalities* by Hayk and Nairi Sedrakyan. One questions asks us to prove $2^{n-1} \geq n$ where $n$ is a natural number (the authors' convention is that 0 is not a natural number).

My solution is as follows: $2^{n-1}=(1+1)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1 \choose k}={n-1 \choose 0}+...+{n-1 \choose n-1}$. The sum ${n-1 \choose 0}+...+{n-1 \choose n-1}$ has $n$ terms and each term is $\geq1$, so this proves the inequality.

The authors give a different proof which I am not sure I understand. They note that $1 \lt 2 \lt2^2 \lt ... \lt 2^{n-1}$. They then note that the number of positive integers $1, 2, ...,2^{n-1}$ is $n$. They say the proof of the desired inequality follows.

I have two questions.

First, does my proof check out?

Second, I'm not entirely clear about their proof. If I had to guess, I would say their proof relies on an unstated step, namely that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^k=2^{n-1}-1$. Since $\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^k$ has $n-1$ terms each of which $\geq1$, then $\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^k \geq n-1$ and so $2^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^k+1 \geq n$. Am I right about why their proof works? Or is there an even simpler explanation for why their proof works?

Comment: If you have $n$ DISTINCT positive integers, then the greatest among these must be greater than or equal to $n$. That is the proof provided by the book. Your proof is good too.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Ah! Okay, that makes a lot of sense, and I look rather dumb for not picking that up immediately. Thank you!

Comment: On second thought I could have phrased it better: there are only $n-1$ distinct positive integers smaller than $n$ so if you have $n$ distinct positive integers at least one will be greater than or equal to $n$